# How to get the seconds off of firestore datebase timestamp?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How to get the seconds from the firestore datebase timestamp in react native

i tried this

```
const expried = this.props.my.expireDate

    alert(expried)
    console.log(expried)
```

the `this.props.expireDate` is a field name in the datebase with a firebase timestamp

```
const expried = this.props.my.expireDate.Timestamp.seconds

    alert(expried)
    console.log(expried)
```

the console log for the first example is show

```
Timestamp {
nanoseconds: 0,
seconds: 1562524200
}
```

and the second example is throwing an error of undefined

Comment: You need `this.props.my.expireDate.seconds` (the log output means that `this.props.my.expireDate` is an object of type `Timestamp`)

Comment: that didn't work @ChrisG

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API documentation for Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp), the way to get the seconds component for a Timestamp object is through the [getSeconds()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp.html#getSeconds()) method.

Comment: thanks @DougStevenson could you please show how to use this method in react native

Comment: A method call is the same in pretty much any programming language. Is there some specific code that doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: why i asked @DougStevenson  is because i tried this ``` this.props.my.expireDate.getSeconds()``` and it throw an error